# VS 2013 preview - sqlConnection.Open() crashing

Tags: visual-studio-2013

This code works perfectly in VS 2010 and 2012.

```vb
Dim cmdText As String = "select * from master.dbo.sysdatabases where name=N'" & database & "'"
Dim bRet As Boolean = False
Using sqlConnection As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection(connString)
    Try
        sqlConnection.Open()
        Using sqlCmd As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand(cmdText, sqlConnection)
            Using reader As SqlDataReader = sqlCmd.ExecuteReader
                bRet = reader.FieldCount > 1
                reader.Close()
            End Using
        End Using
    Catch ex As SqlException
        MsgBox("Error Trying to Connect to database " & database & vbNewLine & ex.Message, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
    Finally
        sqlConnection.Close()
    End Try
End Using
```

But when I run it in 2013 this is the error I get at the sqlConnection.Open() command: -

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.ExecutionEngineException'
>   occurred in System.Transactions.dll
>
> If there is a handler for this exception, the program may be safely
>   continued.

I have found and tried http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/791339/fatalexecutionengineerror
But to no avail
Has anyone any pointers?
I am stuck.

Comment: try it with the RC ;-) http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/deu/2013-downloads